# Is dynamic DNS the only possible way to establish a connection between two routers with temporally IPs?

Tags: ip, internet, dynamic-dns

[image]

the situation is as follows. My and my friends Pcs are connected within a WLAN with a local IP to a router, the router gets its global IP from different ISP with a limited pool of IPs, so the ISPs have to allocate both of us temporalilly IPs. On the Picture the dotted line is the established connection between our PCs realized by dyn DNS. Is dyn DNS the only possible mean to realize a connection in this situation ?

Comment: DynDNS doesn't realise a connection, it just gives you a possibility to obtain the IP address the ISP provided to one of you. You could also copy that IP address to some shared location, or give it to your friend on the phone.

Comment: thanks, so if i got you right, the dyn DNS sends every time the new IP of the partner, so they both can reastablish the connection, but in the usual way , not through a special dyn Dyns server or router ?

Comment: Indeed. You must have setup one of your routers, or one of your systems to do so. Depending on what software you are using fro PC to PC, you might have had to open ports. For programs like Skype, DynDNS is not necessary as the server knows about the IPs of the clients and makes these talk to each other.